# Java Password Creation- Must have certain parameters

Tags: java

I have a homework assignement that involves prompting the user to create a password, and then checking to make sure certain parameters are met (must have 2 upper case, 3 lowercase and 1 digit).

This program must also reprompt the user if the requirements are not met.

I'm having trouble on the reprompting part of the process, as I'm not sure how to get it to reinitiate. Am I counting incorrectly?

Code is below:

```
     import java.util.Scanner;


    public class ValidatePassword
     {
    public static void main(String[] args)
     {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     int upperCount = 0;
     int lowerCount = 0;
     int digitCount = 0;


     //Greeting

     System.out.println("Setting up your password is easy!");
     System.out.println("The system will prompt if additional parameters are needed.");
     System.out.println("Please enter your preferred password:");

     // System in for password

     String password = input.nextLine();


     // Counting the number of each input
     for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++)
        {
        char ch = password.charAt(i);
        if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
           upperCount++;
        else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
           lowerCount++;
        else if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
           digitCount++;
        }

     // Parameter Check

     if (upperCount < 2)
        System.out.println("You must use at least 2 UpperCase Characters"); 
     if (lowerCount < 3)
        System.out.println("You must use at least 3 Lower Case Characters");
     if (digitCount < 1)
        System.out.println("You must use at least 1 Number");          
     if (upperCount > 2 && lowerCount > 3 && digitCount > 1)
        System.out.println("Valid Password");              


  }
```

}

Comment: `boolean isInputValid; do { // your current code here and decide the validity of the input} while (!isInputValid)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `do-while` loop as follows:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean valid = false;
do {
    int upperCount = 0;
    int lowerCount = 0;
    int digitCount = 0;

    //Greeting
    System.out.println("Setting up your password is easy!");
    System.out.println("The system will prompt if additional parameters are needed.");
    System.out.println("Please enter your preferred password:");

    // System in for password
    String password = input.nextLine();

    // Counting the number of each input
    for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++){
        char ch = password.charAt(i);
        if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
            upperCount++;
        else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
            lowerCount++;
        else if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
            digitCount++;
    }

    // Parameter Check
    if (upperCount < 2)
        System.out.println("You must use at least 2 UpperCase Characters"); 
    if (lowerCount < 3)
        System.out.println("You must use at least 3 Lower Case Characters");
    if (digitCount < 1)
        System.out.println("You must use at least 1 Number"); 
    valid = (upperCount >= 2 && lowerCount >= 3 && digitCount >= 1);
    if (valid)
        System.out.println("Valid Password");              
}while(!valid);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (CONDITION) {
    doAThing();
}
```

or:

```
do {
    doAThing();
} while (CONDITION);
```

are the java constructors you are looking for. These constructs will repeat what's in the braces until the condition is no longer met, with the do/while construct guaranteeing you at least one cycle through, whereas the while{} construct will run zero times if the condition isn't met right at the start. CONDITION can be anything; including 'true', as you can also use the `break;` command to stop the loop and continue on beyond the (do)/while construct.

As a side-note, requiring passwords to have certain properties, other than a minimum length, is a bad idea. See also: NIST recommendations. If you demand that a password contains an uppercase letter, the user will just uppercase the first letter. if a digit is required, they will append a '1' to the end. If a special character is required, they'll append a !, also at the end. Therefore, these demands do not improve the entropy of a password whatsoever, and are just annoying / actually serve to reduce. I get that it's homework, but it's good to be aware that you're being taught very bad habits with this exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the whole code in a method and recursively call itself when it's invalid and does nothing when it reaches valid.

```java
public class ValidatePassword {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ValidatePassword main = new ValidatePassword();
        main.validatePassword();
    }

    void validatePassword() {

        int upperCount = 0;
        int lowerCount = 0;
        int digitCount = 0;

        //Greeting
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Setting up your password is easy!");
        System.out.println("The system will prompt if additional parameters are needed.");
        System.out.println("Please enter your preferred password:");

        // System in for password

        String password = input.nextLine();


        // Counting the number of each input
        for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
            char ch = password.charAt(i);
            if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
                upperCount++;
            else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
                lowerCount++;
            else if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
                digitCount++;
        }

        // Parameter Check
        if (upperCount < 2) {
            System.out.println("You must use at least 2 UpperCase Characters");
            validatePassword();
        } else if (lowerCount < 3) {
            System.out.println("You must use at least 3 Lower Case Characters");
            validatePassword();
        } else if (digitCount < 1) {
            System.out.println("You must use at least 1 Number");
            validatePassword();
        } else if (upperCount > 2 && lowerCount > 3 && digitCount > 1) {
            System.out.println("Valid Password");
        }
    }
}
```